# Preenchimento condicional

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba, formatação-condicional

Estou precisando de uma ajuda com VBA.

Minha dúvida é a seguinte:

Preciso que a célula "B" e "C" recebam um valor específico quando eu digitar um valor na célula "A":

---

Por exemplo:
Quando eu digitar o valor "1" na célula "A", a Célula "B" deve receber 'MOTO' e a Célula "C" deve receber 'CARRO'

Quando eu digitar o valor "2" na célula "A", a Célula "B" deve receber 'CASA' e a Célula "C" deve receber 'APARTAMENTO'

Quando eu digitar o valor "3" na célula "A", a Célula "B" deve receber 'CACHORRO' e a Célula "C" deve receber 'GATO'

Como se os números digitados na célula "A" fossem códigos que alteram o comportamento das células seguintes!

---

Edit_1:
haverão momentos em que a célula B e C receberão valores (a partir do teclado) diferentes de CACHORRO e GATO, por isso precisa ser uma função ou código que se comporte como a formatação condicional

---

Desde já agradeço!

Comment: Não sei se entendi mas talvez a função PROCV (ou PROCH) possa ajuda-lo.

Comment: Na verdade, imagino como usar PROCV ou H... a ideia é essas informações existirem apenas na fórmula ou no VBA, a funcionalidade dela é exatamente a mesma da formatação condicional, só que ao invés de pintar a célula ou a borda, ela preenche a célula com um texto pré definido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplo clique em Planilha1(Planilha1), como na imagem. Pode mudar, no seu caso, porém basta fazer o este procedimento na planilha na qual você quer que o código seja executado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Coloque o seguinte código:

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
                Select Case Range("A1").Value
                    Case 1
                        Range("B1").Value = "MOTO"
                        Range("C1").Value = "CARRO"
                    Case 2
                        Range("B1").Value = "CASA"
                        Range("C1").Value = "APARTAMENTO"
                    Case 3
                        Range("B1").Value = "CACHORRO"
                        Range("C1").Value = "GATO"
                    Case Else
                        Range("B1").Value = ""
                        Range("C1").Value = ""
                End Select
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Peço desculpas Paulo, esqueci de informar que haverão momentos em que a célula B e C receberão valores (a partir do teclado) diferentes de CACHORRO e GATO, por isso precisa ser uma função ou código que se comporte como a formatação condicional entende?

Agradeço imensamente a sua ajuda e vou editar a pergunta.
Se não fosse esse detalhe a sua solução resolveria com certeza.

Comment: Beleza então vou alterar o código, aguarde.

Comment: @ChristianO.Santos código alterado.

Comment: O código funciona perfeitamente, muito obrigado pela ajuda @Paulo Vieira.

Deu tudo certo.